# Bypass/change the 'Changes that you made may not be saved' prompt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, logout, prompt

I need to log a user out of an application automatically if there is no interaction for a period of time.

However, when I perform the redirect to log the user out, the browser prompts 'Are you sure you want to leave' when changes are made to a [Stimulsoft](https://www.stimulsoft.com/) report.

How can I bypass this? If changes are made, then the user forgets to log out and save their changes, a malicious user could just come and press the cancel and have access to all the data in the system without allowing this auto-logout to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you are fine!
I suggest you to make ajax request to log out link and then refresh the page after success.

```
$.get('url/of/logout/', function(){location.reload()})
```

with jquery. You can look for equivalent on axios or ajax primitiv function

Comment: Thanks. So this doesn't seem to prevent the 'Leave' prompt from showing and redirect the user. I need to force logout regardless of changes.